# why npm is not responding when using the keyword npm in command prompt

Tags: node.js, npm

[image]I'm trying to use npm intsall, but it doesn't respond anything
even `npm -v` is not working, node and npm is installed.

It stays still like this.

[image: click here to view image]

I have installed node
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRF0z.png)

Path for installed node js

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

[click here to view path image for node on my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhevT.png)

Comment: The image you provided doesn't show that you have installed node. Please provide more details.

Comment: Which os you're using ?

Comment: windows 10.....

Comment: try with admin permission and whether it is install globally or not

Comment: yes, I tried with admin and node is globally installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the **new solution** . Try out this .

In the home directory, there was an entry of .npmrc, and this was probably creating a conflict with the default configuration of the npm inside node. By removing .npmrc from user home did the trick.

**Note: For windows this file will be inside user folder.**


You can find the location of your personal .npmrc using the following command

```
STEP-1) -    npm config get userconfig
```

On Windows it may look like: C:\Users\pushprajsinh.npmrc

```
(Replacing pushprajsinh with your username)
```

Step-2) - Once you get the path of `.nprc` file , *remove* that file. 
(Note:- it might be hidden)

Try out this solution

Comment: where do I have to create directory?

Comment: that's also not working and I'm not trying to run npm intsall,  I'm just trying to check npm version, whenever I type npm, it stays black without any response, in the above screen shot

Comment: Uninstall your npm  and try to install it again .

Comment: To check version, type `npm -v`.

Comment: The problem is whenever I type npm it stays still, and doesn't respond anything

Comment: My issue is still not resolved, can anyone help me with this

Comment: Yes i will . @sarank

Comment: What do I have  to do

Comment: Look at the updated code and follow the steps . @sarank

Answer (score 0):

Check if your node/npm is installed in a directory with blank spaces in the name. This cause problems in Windows.

Comment: can you post the entire route where do you have installed it?

Comment: C:\Program Files\nodejs had an blank space in C:\Program Files. In windows this cause problems. Im sure 100%  this your problem. Try to create a folder out of Program Files and install node there.

Comment: Yes, is a common problem in Windows. StackOverflow have a lot of question about this problem.

Comment: can you post the new route you installed it?

Comment: this my my new route C:\programfiles_nodejs

Comment: Close and open a new cmd, dont use the same to after install it, then try npm -v in the new cmd. If that not works(that I doub it), you have here a official guide https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm

Answer (score 0):

Reason may be- proxy .

check what is the output of

```
npm install --verbose
```

Comment: whenever I start with npm it stays black without any response